# How do you create a newsletter using Exim filter?

Tags: exim

I would like to use an Exim filter file to create a newsletter: accepting mail from specified contributor addresses, then forwarding on to specified subscriber addresses. The below works, but is there a more elegant and robust approach?

```
# Exim filter
if
    $reply_address contains "eric@i.com" or
    $reply_address contains "graham@c.com"
then
    seen 
    deliver john@c.com
    deliver michael@p.com
    deliver terry@gj.com
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a sender address to determine recipients is unusual.  I would just an alias file. You could base it off the system alias router:

**exim.conf**

```
system_aliases:

  driver = redirect
  allow_fail
  allow_defer
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/aliases}}
  file_transport = address_file
  pipe_transport = address_pipe
```

**/etc/aliases**

```
mailinglist: john@c.com, michael@p.com, terry@gj.com
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little more? How does this allow for a given list of contributors?

Comment: use the alias file to map a pseudo-address to a list of reciepents

Comment: What about the contributors?- people (here eric and graham) allowed to post **to** the newsletter?

Answer (score 0):

Use this configuration to maintain your mailing lists in a single file, one address per line.

**exim.conf**

```
# append "mailinglist" to local domains so that "mailinglist" is
# recognized as a domain we handle.  Alternatively, you could just
# use your own domain and not bother with this

domainlist local_domains = @ : localhost : localhost.localdomain : mydomain.com : mailinglist

...

begin routers

...

mailing_lists:
  driver = redirect
  domains = mailinglist
  no_more
  file = /etc/exim/mailinglists/$local_part
  no_check_local_user
  forbid_pipe
  forbid_file
  errors_to = myusername@mydomain.net
```

**/etc/exim/mailinglists/list01**

```
john@c.com
michael@p.com
terry@gj.com
```

**send test message to mailinglist "list01"**

```
echo body | mail -s Test list01@mailinglist
```

Comment: As above: what about the contributors?- people (here eric and graham) allowed to post **to** the newsletter?